# How to resize UITabBarController content view in iOS7?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, ios7, uitabbar

Has anyone been able to resize the content view for an iOS 7 UITabBarController? In previous versions it consisted of two views. A UITabBar and a UITransitionView. The transition view was the content view. However as of iOS 7 SDK the UITransitionView is fullscreen and setting its size does nothing.

I need to resize the content view as I want to display an ad above the UITabBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reach the actual content view on iOS 7 (inside the UIViewControllerWrapper) via this

```
UIView *viewToResize = [[transitionView.subviews[0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

WHen you then resize that view, you should obtain the same effect as resizing the UITransitionView.